# Dagger 2 returns null after injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to make an injection using Dagger 2, but it always returns null. I think I am doing all right, but anyway it does not work.

Here is the application class:

```
public class ApplicationSA extends Application {

private static AppComponent appComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create();
}

public static AppComponent getComponent() {
    return appComponent;
}

}
```

The component interface:

```
@Component(modules = {
        SnoreDetectorClass.class,
        AudioRecorderClass.class
})

public interface AppComponent {
    void injectsMainFunctionalityActivity(Activity activity);
}
```

An the main class where I am trying to get the object:

```
public class MainFunctionalityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    AudioRecorderClass audioRecorderClass;
    @Inject
    SnoreDetectorClass snoreDetectorClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ApplicationSA.getComponent().injectsMainFunctionalityActivity(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("TESTING","audioRecorderClass= "+audioRecorderClass); // always null
        Log.d("TESTING","snoreDetectorClass= "+snoreDetectorClass); // always null
...
}
```

And here are the module classes:

```
@Module
public class AudioRecorderClass {

    public interface AudioRecorderInterface {
        void AudioRecorder_hasUpdate(double amplitude_in_dB);
    }
    public AudioRecorderInterface delegate = null;

    @Provides
    AudioRecorderClass provideAudioRecorderClass(Activity activity) {
        delegate = (AudioRecorderInterface)activity;
        return new AudioRecorderClass();
    }
...

@Module
public class SnoreDetectorClass {

    @Provides
    SnoreDetectorClass provideSnoreDetectorClass() {
        return new SnoreDetectorClass();
    }
...
```

What am I doing wrong ? Why the objects are always null ?

Comment: Have you added the dagger annotation processor to your build.gradle?

Comment: Sure:
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I see what is going on here. You cannot inject into a subclass. So in your `AppComponent` you cannot have

```
 void injectsMainFunctionalityActivity(Activity activity);
```

you must inject with

```
 void injectsMainFunctionalityActivity(MainFunctionalityActivity activity);
```

As a side note I would suggest not combining your injector and your model class. Better to have separation of concerns. Keep them separate

Comment: Just as the error says. You are trying to provide an instance of AudioRecorderClass, but your provider (disingenuously) says that in order to provide an AudioRecorderClass, it requires a MainFunctionalityActivity. So it needs a way to provide that. You have no provider for that activity though (nor should you). This is why you should separate out your module from your AudioRecorderClass (as well as your SnoreDetectorClass) into a separate module. You can remove MainFunctionalityActivity as a parameter in your @Provides and then use a separate dedicated mechanism to set the delegate.

Comment: Ah. Looks like you figured it out. Great :) My comment now does not really reply to your removed error, but i will leave it up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specifically tell dagger which activity will be injected here, not use the super class Activity but rather your own implementation of the Activity class :

```
void injectsMainFunctionalityActivity(Activity activity);
```

change to:

```
void injectsMainFunctionalityActivity(MainFunctionalityActivity activity);
```